# How to implement inheritance correctly on Angular Service

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm currently implementing a GenericService which should receive as a parameter within the constructor a baseURL. But it's also injecting HttpClient and another service within it's constructor.
So I'm kinda confused what would be the best practice in this case. Should I declare the services in the GenericService as Abstract? Currently I thought it would be for the best to go with the following but I'd like some opinion if it's fine as it is.

```js
export class GenericService<T> {

  constructor(baseURL: string, private http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService) { ... }
```

```js
const endpoint = `someEndPointURL`
export class ChildService extends GenericService<T> {


  constructor(http: HttpClient, apiService: ApiService) {
    super(endpoint, http, configApi)
  }
}
```